# Facebook group wall on some other website

Tags: authentication, permissions, fbml, facebook-wall, facebook-group

I made a application which shows facebook group wall on the other website. I would like to know if it is possible that users which comes to this other website don't have to grant their permissions. The facebook group is public and everything is shared without any special permissions. Also would like to know if it is possible to show group wall feed without user logged in?

Do you have any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

"The facebook group is public and everything is shared without any special permissions."

One of the strange things about the Graph API, to get public information from much of it, will require an access token, even though that information is "public".  I've scratched my head about that for a long time, and haven't come up with any other answer than "the API is provided by Facebook and we must play by their rules when in their sandbox".

So, you will need to get an access token from at least one person to do what you are requesting.  (At least you wouldn't have to ask every user!)

You will need to ask your user for `user_group` access and then you can grab `{group_id}/feed`.  What you might want to do is get a non-expiring token from one of the original members or even yourself by requesting `offline_access`.  Then always use that token to get the feed.  (Remember, when you change your password, the offline_access token will be invalidated and will need to get a new one).

Comment: Thank you for you answer it was usefull.